# Identifying a PGP encrypted file

Tags: java, encryption, pgp, openpgp

Is there a way to identify a PGP encrypted file based on the file content (like the way a ZIP file can be identified by looking for letters "PK" at the beginning of the file)? Is there any magic number associated with PGP encrypted files?

We receive multiple files from a client and don't have an idea which ones are PGP encrypted. I need to write Java code to identify the PGP files and decrypt them automatically. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. You may have to go about it in reverse, run tests for other file types, and suppose it's encrypted if it doesn't meet any of the other format tests.

Comment: i'm not sure if you can choose certain container formats that might come along with a magic identifier, but one of the design criteria for cipheroutputs usually is ... the ciphertext has to be indistinguishable from random bytes ... so maybe run a distribution calculation ober the file and see if it looks like pure randomness... ;) ... won't tell you if it was pgp or another cipher suite though

Comment: Take a look in the OpenPGP message format specification ([RFC 4880](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880))

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [OpenPGP Library for Java](https://www.didisoft.com/java-openpgp/examples/inspect-the-contents-of-an-openpgp-archive/#Analyze) (commercial product). Here is a short example:

```
PGPInspectLib inspect = new PGPInspectLib();
if (inspect.isPublicKeyEncrypted(dataFileName)) {
 // file is PGP encrypted
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft

Comment: DidSoft is a paid library, I was looking for some open source solution. Does this inspection have any performance impact?

Comment: I don't think that there will be any significant overhead, but you shall test this for your use case